# How to access the prototype object from another object within it

Tags: javascript

My knowledge of prototypes is still in its infancy, so please bear with me. I have a main object that is initialised via `var book = new book()`;

I initiate some prototype functions:

```
book = function(){
    this.init();
}

book.prototype.init = function() {
    //etc.
}
```

And I also initialise an object:

```
book.prototype.bookmarks = {
    init : function(){
        //How can I access book from this function?
    }
}
```

I mean I could use `book.someFunction()` but I'm just curious if there's a way to properly access the top level object. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'll try and clarify anything unclear. Thanks

Comment: No questions are stupid, If you are unsure it Doesnt hurt to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not automatically. That is, you have to tell the subobject what the top object is, so in the `init` function of `book`, you'd get something like this:

```
init = function() {
    // Create the bookmarks instance and assign it to the property of book.
    this.bookmarks = new bookmarks();
    // Tell the bookmarks about me, the book object.
    this.bookmarks.book = this;
}
```

Comment: You call bookmarks as a function yet in my example it's `bookmarks = {}`. Doing `this.bookmarks.book` would allow me to access it using `this.book` in the bookmarks init function, correct?

Comment: Correct. I thought bookmarks was a prototype too, but for anonymous objects it would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm likely making some assumptions here, but this might be along the lines of what you are looking for in terms of accessing the instantiated book.

```
function Book(title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.init();
}

Book.prototype = {
    title: null,
    page:  null,
    init: function() {
        // Initialize book
    },
    bookmark: function(page) {
        if (page) {
            this.page = page;
        } else {
            return this.page || 'No Bookmark';
        }
    }
}

var myBook = new Book('The Catcher in the Rye');
myBook.bookmark('pg 36');
myBook.bookmark(); // => pg 36
```